# Specify CA chain in AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using a SSL certificate for my custom domain. This certificate needs five intermediate authorities to get to the root CA, and without them some browsers (pronounce: Chrome) will work, but others (Firefox, Android browsers) will fail.

Is there any way to specify more than two CAs in the PEM file? AppEngine complains when I try to put the whole certification chain (as documented, it accepts only two CAs in the PEM file). Is it my only option to drop my current certificate and go with Verisign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question, there is no way to do this at the present time. Switch to a CA that uses a single intermediate authority (DigiCert combines this with a superb technical support) and move on.

**UPDATE**: Starting today, GAE is supporting a chain of up to five CA authorities.